# Firebase service worker and Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, service-worker

I want to show a notification with action buttons.
This is only possible with the serviceWorker.showNotification API.

I have an Angular 9 application with the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** service worker as mentioned in the Firebase Messaging docs.

The service worker is used when the page is in the background.
In the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` I send the notification with:

```
self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
```

If the app is in the foreground, I need to show the same notification with actions buttons.
So I need in the Angular Service TypeScript file to access also the same firebase service worker, but `self.registration` does of course not work.

How can I access the already registered Firebase service worker to show a notification with action buttons in my Angular TypeScript file?

Comment: Are you loading `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in angular.json?

Comment: Yes of course:
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],

Answer (score 1):

create firebase-messaging-sw.js Push messaging requires a service worker. This allows your app to detect new messages, even after the app has been closed by the user. and create this file in the same directory of manifest.json file which is in src/ directory.

***Note:- Before importing the below script you need to check the latest version it's better if you import the latest version of the CDN link, so here i importing 7.6.0 version links.***

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: “from firebase config”,
    authDomain: “from firebase config”,
    databaseURL: “from firebase config”,
    projectId: “from firebase config”,
    storageBucket: “from firebase config”,
    messagingSenderId: “from firebase config”,
    appId: “from firebase config”,
    measurementId: “from firebase config”
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

we need to register these files in angular-cli.json

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js", // add this one
    "src/manifest.json" // this one also 
]
```

And you can do reference below code for service code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
    currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
    (_messaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
    }
    )
    }
    requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
    (token) => {
    console.log(token);
    },
    (err) => {
    console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    }
    );
    }
    receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
    (payload) => {
    console.log("new message received. ", payload);
    this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    })
    }
}
```

let’s understand its functions
`requestPermission()` : Browser/ device will ask to user for permission to receive notification. After permission is granted by the user, firebase will return a token that can use as a reference to send a notification to the `browser.receiveMessage()` : This function will be triggered when a new message has received.

Comment: Thanks but if I want to add declare global I get the following error message: https://ibb.co/9ZvfKh3

Comment: Can you use other variable name instead of self?

Comment: Yes I have tried it with self2. No error message anymore while compiling, but at runtime I get: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'registration' of undefined

Comment: Can you share me your component that use `self.registeration.showNotification`?

Comment: pls check. I updated answer. If anything is not understand, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the details. But I have all from your answer already working. I get the message from Firebase in foreground AND background and so on. But I need to show a browser notification with serviceWorker.showNotification inside the message.service.tst! The same as I already do in the service worker itself.

Comment: This wont work with Angular 12. and firebase 8.9.1 There is no more  this.angularFireMessaging.messaging only  this.angularFireMessaging.message ... And it is still not working in my case